# bower: no suitable angular version

Tags: bower, angular-ui-grid

Maybe I don't understand SemVer syntax or maybe I don't understand bower (I have version 1.4.1), but I have an app whose **bower.json** is:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "description": "My AngularJS Project....",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.x",
    "angular-route": "1.3.x",
    "angular-loader": "1.3.x",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-ui-grid": "~3.0.0-rc.20",
    "angular-spinkit": "~0.3.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.4",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.x",
    "file-saver.js": "~1.20150507.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
  }
}**
```

When I do a '**bower update**', it is “unable to find a suitable version for angular”, but I don't understand why not.  Here's the output (#1 seems to be the problem):

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#>=1.2.16 <=1.3.x which resolved to 1.2.28 and is required by angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-rc.22
    2) angular#1.3.16 which resolved to 1.3.16 and is required by angular-animate#1.3.16, angular-loader#1.3.16, angular-mocks#1.3.16, angular-route#1.3.16
    3) angular#1.3.x which resolved to 1.3.16 and is required by MyApp
    4) angular#>=1.3.0 which resolved to 1.3.16 and is required by angular-bootstrap#0.13.0
    5) angular#* which resolved to 1.3.16 and is required by angular-spinkit#0.3.3
```

So my reading of that output is that all packages would be happy with version 1.3.16 of angular, except for **angular-ui-grid** (“resolved to 1.2.28”)  But why?   Isn't 1.3.16 >=1.2.16 <=1.3.x ?   And so isn't version 1.3.16 of Angular a suitable version? isn't it the ONLY suitable version?  or maybe I'm misunderstanding what bower is trying to tell me.

I do understand that I can select one of the choices and even add a '!' to persist my choice, but I don't understand why a choice is needed.

Thanks

Comment: Strange, I noticed we were having this problem when I set the dependency spec to ">=1.2.16 <=1.3.x", and I thought changing 1.3.x to 1.3.16 would let it install that release. It seemed like it did in a test I did.

Comment: I also set up a plunker to test the version spec with semver.js: http://plnkr.co/edit/dHvHpgK53mtEcgI2goDQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

c0bra - thanks for setting up that plunker - it helped me to easily verify what I believe I finally (after lots of digging) determined is the problem:

there seems to be a bug in older versions of semver.js - I traced down, down, down into the code and the <=1.3.x gets morphed into <=1.3.0-0, and that means that 1.3.16 fails that test.

But that bug has been fixed in the NPM-delivered semver module - I was able to use your plunker to demonstrate to myself that 1.3.16 passes the test with 'latest' semver code, just as you set it up, but fails when I switch to older versions of semver (e.g. "^2.3.0", which seems to be what the bower package requires in its packages.json).

But even the latest bower on github seems to have that ^2.3.0 dependency for semver.  So I'll see if I can submit a request to whoever maintains bower to get that upgraded.   But I do not see much activity on bower/github of late.

In the meantime, I guess I'm stuck with being forced to answer the question above, since I'm using NPM to get bower, I don't think I can easily override it's semver dependency.